# Ошибка: Temporary failure in name

Tags: php

Всем привет. Работал скрипт на сайте, но пару дней назад начал выдавать ошибку. Как исправить скрипт? Вот кусок кода, где ошибка:

```
$get = file_get_contents("http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=myid&Query=".urlencode($s)."&Sources=Web&Market=en-US&Web.Count=10");
```

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]:
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: Temporary failure in name
> resolution in
> /home01/jqnq/pzxtip/home/mysite.net/lol.php
> on line 8
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=myid&Query=dating&Sources=Web&Market=en-US&Web.Count=10)
> [function.file-get-contents]: failed
> to open stream:
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: Temporary failure in name
> resolution in
> /home01/jqnq/pzxtip/home/mysite.net/lol.php
> on line 8

Comment: Семь бед, один ресет =)
А если серьезно, думаю, это траблы окружения, очень непросто их отлавливать. Можно попробовать кэши, свопы почистить.

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents` - не используйте эту функцию! Она работает только тогда, когда на сервере, откуда вы пытаетесь что-то получить это разрешено.

Пользуйте cURL и будет вам счастье.

Comment: В том-то и дело что и тут выдает ошибку.


Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_contents_curl() in /home01/jqnq/pzxtip/home/mysite.net/xdfsdsd.php on line 2

$get = file_get_contents_curl("http://api.bing.net/

Comment: file_get_contents_curl  - а это что за функция?